# Vue JS filter results based on checkbox array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've built a Vue JS search component to search and filter a list of properties for a property website. The search component is listed on every page, so it makes sense for me to use a URL search query which takes me to the main properties page and then use something like `this.$route.query.search` to get the value from my query and store in a variable.

The property data is coming from a JSON file which essentially looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "sold": false,
      "isFeatured": true,
      "slug": "green-park-talbot-green-cf72-8rb",
      "address": "Green Park, Talbot Green CF72 8RB",
      "county": "Rhondda Cynon Taf",
      "price": "695000",
      "features": ["Modern fitted kitchen", "Integrated appliances", "Front and rear gardens"],
      "type": "Semi-Detached",
      "bedrooms": "3"
    }
}
```

My search query would be something like this:

```
/properties/?search=Address%20Here&type=Apartment&bedrooms=2&county=Maesteg
```

Which then would filter each thing.

How this works is quite simple, inside my data object I have my variables which get each query and store them as follows:

```
data () {
    return {
      searchAddress: this.$route.query.search,
      searchType: this.$route.query.type,
      searchBedrooms: this.$route.query.bedrooms,
      searchCounty: this.$route.query.county
    }
}
```

And then I have a filter inside the computed area called **filteredProperties** which filters down the properties inside the `v-for` which isn't necessary to show here:

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {
        return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) && property.type.match(this.searchType) && property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) && property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
      });
    }
  }
```

**Now this works absolutely fine and works correctly**... however I now need to modify this to instead of having `<select>` dropdowns which is how you would currently pick the number of bedrooms, or the property type etc, I now need to **replace the property type** `<select>` dropdown with checkboxes so that the user can select multiple property types and essentially add that as an array into the URL.

I'm not quite sure how to modify this part of my filter to be able to look for multiple property types:

```
property.type.match(this.searchType)
```

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

I've recently tried updating my computed filter with the following:

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {

        return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) &&
        this.searchAddress.some(function(val){
          return property.search.match(val)
        }) &&

        property.type.match(this.searchType) &&
        this.searchType.some(function(val){
          return property.type.match(val)
        }) &&

        property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) &&
        this.searchBedrooms.some(function(val){
          return property.bedrooms.match(val)
        }) &&

        property.county.match(this.searchCounty) &&
        this.searchCounty.some(function(val){
          return property.county.match(val)
        })

      });
    }
  }
```

I need the search to work with and without a URL query.

Also tried an if/else statement:

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {
        return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) &&

        if (this.searchType.length > 1) {
          this.searchType.some(function(val){
            return property.type.match(val)
          })
        } else {
          property.type.match(this.searchType)
        } &&

        property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) &&
        property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
      });
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I got it working by doing the following:

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function(){
      return this.properties.filter((property) => {

        let searchTypeMatch;

        if (typeof this.searchType === "object") {
          searchTypeMatch = this.searchType.some(function(val){
            return property.type.match(val)
          })
        } else {
          searchTypeMatch = property.type.match(this.searchType)
        }

      return property.address.match(this.searchAddress) &&
        searchTypeMatch &&
        property.bedrooms.match(this.searchBedrooms) &&
        property.county.match(this.searchCounty)
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: hi just curious why you are using `match(...)` to see if the given address is contained in your data set ? Also, after you change it to checkbox are you guaranteed that you will get an array in your query parameter. If yes then the modification will be pretty lean using `.some(...)` of the Array.prototype.

Comment: Could I change `.match()` to `.some()` for that particular one then? And what other options are there?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use JSON for the query parameters in order to serialize/deserialize the arrays.

```
data () {
    return {
      searchAddress: this.$route.query.search ? JSON.parse(this.$route.query.search) : [],
      searchType: this.$route.query.type ? JSON.parse(this.$route.query.type) : [],
      searchBedrooms: this.$route.query.bedrooms ? JSON.parse(this.$route.query.bedrooms) : [],
      searchCounty: this.$route.query.county ? JSON.parse(this.$route.query.county) : []
    }
}
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function()
    {
      return this.properties.filter((property) => 
      {
        return (this.searchAddress.length ? this.searchAddress.some((address) =>
        {
          return property.address.match(address);
        }) : true) && (this.searchType.length ? this.searchType.some((type) =>
        {
          return property.type.match(type);
        }) : true) && (this.searchBedrooms.length ? this.searchBedrooms.some((bedrooms) =>
        {
          return property.bedrooms.match(bedrooms);
        }) : true) && (this.searchCounty.length ? this.searchCounty.some((county) =>
        {
          return property.county.match(county);
        }) : true)
      });
    }
  }
```

Then you send query params like this

```
this.$router.push("/search?search=" + JSON.stringify(searchArray) 
  + "&type=" + JSON.stringify(typeArray)
  + "&bedrooms=" + JSON.stringify(bedroomsArray)
  + "&county=" + JSON.stringify(countyArray)
);
```

Comment: I just tried this, I get: `Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0` when trying to search

Comment: Probably the argument for JSON.parse() has not been generated by JSON.stringify() - you have to first serialize your array(s) before being able to deserialize them.

Comment: `this.$router.push("/search?search="+JSON.stringify(searchArray)+"&type="+JSON.stringify(typeArray)+"&bedrooms="+JSON.stringify(bedroomsArray)+"&county="+JSON.stringify(countyArray));`

Comment: This sounds cool, but it's a generic `<form>` element with a button with an action that points to `/properties` which is my page, not `/search`. Furthermore, it looks like I'd have to tie that code into a click event? So what if they simply press enter? I'm using a get request.

Comment: whether it is `/search` or `/properties` is irrelevant. You should bind to the `submit` event on the form itself (it will catch the Enter) - then prepare the proper URL, set the `form.action` to this URL and then `return true`

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with routing in Vue apps but for the following to work you will have to ensure that `this.$route.query.search` (and the other route properties) is an (are) `[]`(s).

```
return this.searchAddress.some(function(val) {
    return property.address.match(val)
}) && 
this.searchType.some(function(val){
    return property.type.match(val)
}) && ...
```

Let me know if this works for you.

**RE-EDITED**:

Hi, please change the computed property to the following

```
computed: {
    filteredProperties: function () {
        let self = this
        let routeConstraints = ['search', 'type', 'bedrooms', 'county'].filter(function (val) {
            return self.$route.query[val] !== undefined
        })
        if (routeConstraints.length === 0) {
            return self.properties
        } else {
            return routeConstraints.reduce(function (acc, val) {
                return acc.filter(function (property) {
                    //basically I am checking if there is some value in the query parameter that matches properties.
                    if (self.$route.query[val] !== undefined) {
                        //check if the route parameter is an array (object)
                        if (typeof this.searchType === "object") {
                            self.$route.query[val] = [self.$route.query[val]]
                        }
                    }
                    return self.$route.query[val].some(function (item) {
                        //changed the matching condition to indexOf
                        return property[val].match(item).length > 0
                    })
                })
            }, self.properties)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically,

1. I am trying to check what routes values are set from your checkbox selections
2. Using it to filter the properties array.
3. If none are set then all properties are returned.

Hope this works.

Comment: I don't think this will work, I'll try the `.some()`

Comment: This uses `.some(..)`. May I ask why this won't work ?

Comment: If I change `property.type.match(this.searchType)` to `property.type.some(this.searchType)`, it doesn't work. I also tried using your code, that doesn't work either :/

Comment: hi, thanks for checking. could you please print `Array. isArray( this.searchType)` and check if that is `true` and a `typeof this.searchType`. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, an update... I've got it to work now, it returns true and took a bit on tinkering, however, If there's only one item in the array (e.g: one property type) and not multiples it gives me an error: `_this.searchType.some is not a function` but works fine with more than one?

Comment: It doesn't exist unless it's in the URL... so now my search works but doesn't work if nothing is in my url... what are your suggestions? If there a check I can do here?

Comment: it will look ugly :/ but you could say: `this.searchType` && `this.searchType.some(...)` and so on...

Comment: hi, can you update the question with some changes you had to make for my answer ? That way I can see what you did and give a better solution. Like are you using JSON.parse to the query parameter ?

Comment: I've updated my question to try with what you just mentioned, I don't think I'm doing it quite right... I get `_this.searchAddress.some is not a function` when something is in the seach query (url), and when I have no search and just to to `/properties` I get: `Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

Comment: I'm also not using `JSON.parse`, I'm using the original data in my question. Although something additional occoured to me, since my original code worked, and the new code works with more than one, is there like an `if else` statement I could bake in to run something if there is more than 1 item in the array etc?

Comment: Updated my code example again to sort of show you what I was thinking with an if else

Comment: I tried this, it returns all properties if nothing is specified, however if I try to search for something I get: `self.$route.query[val].some is not a function`. Here's an example search query: `/properties/?search=Green%20Park&bedrooms=1&county=Blaenau%20Gwent&type=Semi-Detached&type=Apartment` @82Tuskers

Comment: @RyanHolton hi ... can you please print console.log(acc, val) before the line `return acc.filter(function (property)` and share the output ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it working by updating the computed property. See my additional update in my question for working code.

Comment: @RyanHolton, glad its working now. But, the only question I had is: wouldn't there be multiple selections for bedrooms and county ? I have updated my answer with your check - `if (typeof this.searchType === "object")` . It might make my answer work for those cases too. Its worth a try. Thanks & Cheers